# BeanUtils: Different property names

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

i have a problem with BeanUtils, i need to convert Map to POJO with different property names

entity:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String nickname;
    private int agility;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Target application API returns HashMap (via XML-RPC) with something like that:

```
user_id => "123456"
nickname => "Bob"
agility => 30
```

but my POJO class doesn't have `user_id` property

how to translate property name `user_id` => `id`?

i didn't find any annotations for that case

Comment: Dozer, and similar bean-mapping libs, are your best bet. Also, JSON mapping libs, like you discovered, can be used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeanUtils is not suitable for my case, i used [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library. Gson has feature - convert object to json. After that i convert json into `User` class. `name` property marked by annotation [@SerializedName](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

entity class:

```
class User {
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private int id;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters here
    // .toString
}
```

usage:

```
Map<String,String> apiObject = new HashMap<>();

apiObject.put("user_id","123123");
apiObject.put("name","Bob");

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(values);
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class);

System.out.println(user);
```

example output:

```
User{id=123123, name='Bob'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is permitted to later the HashMap after you received it, you change change the key.

```
map.put("id", map.remove("user_id"));
```

Then use BeanUtils to populate your bean:

```
User usr = new User();
BeanUtils.populate(usr, map);
```

Comment: You can the 20 fields in in a map, and use it to replace key of your data map.

Comment: this solution requires to support fields-replace list, it's not agile. n+1 entities and 20+ fields -> support hell. i think about trick with gson (i'll check and write about that later)